# Union and Struct Initialization

Tags: c, unions

I stumbled across a code based on unions in C. Here is the code:

```
    union    {  
        struct  {  
            char ax[2];  
            char ab[2];  
        } s;  
        struct  {  
            int a;  
            int b;  
        } st;  
    } u ={12, 1}; 

    printf("%d %d", u.st.a, u.st.b);
```

I just couldn't understand how come the output was `268 0`. How were the values initialized?
How is the union functioning here? Shouldn't the output be `12 1`.  It would be great if anyone could explain what exactly is happening here in detail.

I am using a 32 bit processor and on Windows 7.

Comment: And how on earth should the initializer know that you want to initialize `st` and not `s`?

Comment: Had i known , this question wouldn't be here.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The code doesn't do what you think. Brace-initializes initialize the *first* union member, i.e. `u.s`. However, now the initializer is incomplete and missing braces, since `u.s` contains two arrays. It should be somethink like: `u = { { {'a', 'b'}, { 'c', 'd' } } };`

You should always **compile with all warnings**, a decent compiler should have told you that something was amiss. For instance, GCC says, `missing braces around initialiser (near initialisation for ‘u.s’)` and `missing initialiser (near initialisation for ‘u.s.ab’)`. Very helpful.

In C99 you can take advantage of named member initialization to initialize the second union member: `u = { .st = {12, 1} };` (This is not possible in C++, by the way.) The corresponding syntax for the first case is `` `u = { .s = { {'a', 'b'}, { 'c', 'd' } } }; ``, which is arguably more explicit and readable!

Comment: Actually you need *two* extra sets of braces (one for the union, one for the struct, and one for the array): `u = {{{'a', 'b'}, {'c', 'd'}}}`.

Comment: @KerrekSB Thank you. Probably the best answer. Could you also explain that why is the output `268 0` now that the initialization problem is over.

Comment: @NiteeshMehra: 256 + 12... plus a large handful of luck

Comment: @KerrekSB Thanks I think I got it, correct me if am wrong : The bits are set like this `00000001 00001100` = 256+8+4 = 268. Right ? But then why is u.st.b = 0 ?

Comment: @NiteeshMehra: No, it would have to be little-endian order to make sense. As for the rest: As I said, a lot of luck. This is undefined behaviour, anything could happen. It just turned out that the memory was zeroed at that point.

Comment: @NiteeshMehra: Here is what happened.  s.ax[2] and s.ab[2] were packed into 4 bytes in little-endian order.  Your initialization initialized s.ax[0] to 12 (0x0C) and s.ax[1] to 1 (0x01).  Everything else was initialized to 0.  (I don't know whether or not this is "spec" behavior, but it is what I would expect to happen.)  Assuming you are using 32-bit ints, the resulting data layout is as follows (lowest byte on the left):  0C 01 00 00 00 00 00 00   So when you printed the first 4-byte int you got 0x0000010C, or 268, and when you printed the second 4-byte int you got 0x00000000, the mystery 0.

Comment: @KerrekSB  In LE order : `01 0C` ?

Comment: @AndrewCottrell So that means the lowest byte was assigned 12 , next byte 1 , and the remaining 6 bytes ( because size of union is 8 bytes cuz of the 2 int? ) were assigned 0 (this would depend upon compiler/machine whatever? ) . Did i get it right? So when i print u.st.a output would be the least 4 bytes (00 00 01 0C = 268) ? And when i would print u.st.b , output would be the remaining 4 bytes (00 00 00 00) ?

Comment: @KerrekSB Right , so that would be `0C 01`. I hope am correct this time?

Comment: @NiteeshMehra Yep, you got it.

Answer (score 6):

Your code uses the default initializer for the union, which is its first member. Both 12 and 1 go into the characters of ax, hence the result that you see (which is very much compiler-dependent).

If you wanted to initialize through the second memmber (`st`) you would use a designated initializer:

```
union {  
    struct {  
        char ax[2];  
        char ab[2];  
    } s;  
    struct {  
        int a;  
        int b;  
    } st;  
} u ={ .st = {12, 1}};
```

Answer (score 5):

The code sets `u.s.ax[0]` to 12 and `u.s.ax[1]` to 1. `u.s.ax` is overlayed onto `u.st.a` so the least-significant byte of `u.st.a` is set to 12 and the most-significant byte to 1 (so you must be running on a little-endian architecture) giving a value of 0x010C or 268.

Comment: How come `0x010C` ? Shouldn't that be `0x001C`?

Comment: Thanks I think I got it, correct me if am wrong : The bits are set like this `00000001 00001100` = 256+8+4 = 268. Right ? But then why is u.st.b = 0 ?

Comment: Yes - `00000001` `00001100` is `0x010C`. u.st.b is zero because only two values were provided and these were assigned to `u.s.ax[0]` and `u.s.ax[1]`. These two chars overlay the least-significant end of `u.st.a`, leaving the upper half and `u.st.b` set to zero by default.

Answer (score 2):

A union's size is the maximum size of the largest element that composes the union.  So in this case, your union type has a size of 8-bytes on a 32-bit platform where `int` types are 4-bytes each.  The first member of the union, `s`, though, only takes up 2-bytes, and therefore overlaps with the first 2-bytes of the `st.a` member.  Since you are on a little-endian system, that means that we're overlapping the two lower-order bytes of `st.a`.  Thus, when you initialize the union as it's done with the values `{12, 1}`, you've only initialized the values in the two lower-order bytes of `st.a` ... this leaves the value of `st.b` initialized to `0`.  Thus when you attempt to print out the struct containing the two `int` rather than `char` members of the union, you end up with your results of `128` and `0`.

Comment: The output is `268` and `0`. Why does the first member of the union `s` take up 2 bytes ? Shouldn't it take 4 bytes? It has 2 char array of size 2. So it should be 2*2 = 4. Correct me if i am wrong.

Answer (score 1):

It probably assigned { 12 ,1 } to the first 2 char in **s.ax**.

So in a 32bit int  it's 1*256 + 12 = 268